# Cannot search for negatively scored questions of specific thresholds

Tags: bug, status-completed, downvotes, search, discussions-space

Whenever I type [`score:.-10`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a.-10&searchOn=3) in the search bar, I just see this:

[image: Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

However, ironically, this error does **not** occur if I search for really downvoted posts [`score:.-100`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A.-100) or 'moderately' downvoted posts [`score:.-3`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A.-3). I was not able to reproduce this on [the Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A.-10) or any other site.

I was also able to reproduce this for `-5` `-7` `-8` `-9` and `-11`.

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), the syntax should use two dots, not one. It's strange that your other queries *do* work. But I agree that no query should result in a server error. For that matter, searching for `score:.-10` does work for me, the problem *actually* occurs only once one attempts to sort those results by newest. From further investigation, the issue seems to be specific to the score thresholds `-10` and `-11`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [`score:..-10` by newest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a..-10&searchOn=3) gives error. Even with 2 dots.

Comment: FWIW, the newest such post (which happens to be a question; keep in mind that your query does not specify this) I can find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481961). I don't get consistent, reproducible results (WRT whether there is an error) for the more focused queries I tried in order to find this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just reproduced with [`score:.-8`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a.-8&searchOn=3) and `-7` and `-9`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel And [`-5`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a.-5&searchOn=3) but not `-6` for some reason.

Comment: After some more experiments, looks like there's an issue with a particular type of post. Adding `is:q` or `is:a` or even `is:article` returned a result even with `newest` sort. With `score:..-10` (4693), there is a discrepancy of 1 post, in addition to `is:q` (2105), `is:a` (2586), and `is:article` (1).

Comment: Heads-up - updated my answer. This is Discussions related. I've edited the tags to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for the bug report. This was indeed caused by erroneously returning discussions in search. As intended, discussions are now excluded from both site and network search

Comment: @Berthold would there be a separate way to search for discussions or is searching for discussions going to be limited during the beta?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat At this time there is no search available for Discussions. The best way to find posts about a topic is to use the tag filter on the main list page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for raising this bug. We have rolled out partial fix on the front end, so you should not be getting this error anymore. However we have more work to do to fully resolve the issue on the back end, so I marked this as status-planned. We will follow up when that work is completed.

Answer (score 15):

### This is related to Discussions

[Abdul Aziz Barkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat) has [found the issue](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56877269#56877269):

> Consider this search: `[cicd] [php] [reactjs] [vue.js] is:q created:2023-11-22` it gives 0 results. But if you remove `is:q` it errors out. Coincidentally there's a discussion that matches that exact criteria: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/beta/discussions/77531259/seeking-guidance-on-creating-a-dynamic-website-for-online-food-orders-with-promo

And indeed this is reproducible. Narrowed to just that day:

- `[cicd] [php] [reactjs] [vue.js] is:q created:2023-11-22..2023-11-22` ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcicd%5D+%5Bphp%5D+%5Breactjs%5D+%5Bvue.js%5D+is%3Aq+created%3A2023-11-22..2023-11-22)) - zero results
- `[cicd] [php] [reactjs] [vue.js] created:2023-11-22..2023-11-22` ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcicd%5D+%5Bphp%5D+%5Breactjs%5D+%5Bvue.js%5D+created%3A2023-11-22..2023-11-22)) - error

It does not seem to be just negatively scored Discussions, either. [Here is one which is positively scored](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/beta/discussions/77084750/are-you-using-2fa-with-your-cicd-tool) and searching for it by tags and date shows an error: `[cicd] [github] [gitlab] [multi-factor-authentication] created:2023-09-11..2023-09-11` ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcicd%5D+%5Bgithub%5D+%5Bgitlab%5D+%5Bmulti-factor-authentication%5D+created%3A2023-09-11..2023-09-11))

### Older experimentation

After some experimentation, I can narrow down that `score:-11..-11 created:2023..` ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-11..-11+created%3A2023..)) always throws an error. You do not have to go to the Newest tab.

Seems to be something about the first page of results. Changing the page size to 15 and searching for `score:-11..-11 created:2022..` ([search link with page size 15](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=15&q=score%3a-11..-11%20created%3a2022..&searchOn=3)) will *very often* lead to an error. But if refreshing enough, there is no error. That is because the search results on the default Relevance tab are not stable.

There are 16 results total according to the search and, eventually after enough refreshes the search yields a result:
[image: Search page showing 15 results out of 16]

However, trying to break down by post type does not have an error:

- `score:-11..-11 created:2022.. is:q` ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-11..-11+created%3A2022..+is%3Aq)) has **9** results and works.
- `score:-11..-11 created:2022.. is:a` ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-11..-11+created%3A2022..+is%3Aa)) has **6** results and works.
- `score:-11..-11 created:2022.. is:article` ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-11..-11+created%3A2022..+is%3Aarticle)) has **0** results and works.

The total is 1 off: 9 + 6 + 0 = 15

Trying to go to the second page on the `score:-11..-11 created:2022..` search does not reveal any useful information. There is only one result shown there but it is not completely deterministic which post gets shown. Moreover, I have seen a post *already seen on the first page* being shown on the second one.

---

I can narrow down further searching for`score:-11..-11 created:2023-08-22..2023-08-22` leads to an error every time ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-11..-11+created%3A2023-08-22..2023-08-22)). There is a post with a score of -11 from the 22nd of August that causes an issue.

I tried to find a different post and there is apparently a -6 scored post that is from the 27th of October which also causes an issue, the search query for it is `score:-6..-6 created:2023-10-27..2023-10-27` ([search link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-6..-6+created%3A2023-10-27..2023-10-27)).

Comment: The bug probably happened due to functionality added in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/beta/discussions) which allows some sorting and filtering of discussions by tag. It's probably using the same search functionality as the already present search.